# requests library: how to speed it up?

Tags: python, multithreading, urllib2, python-requests

I am trying to send multiple requests to different web pages. At the moment I am using the "requests" library in multithreading, because I have found it most performing than urllib2. Is it possible to load only a part of the webpage? Do you have any other idea to speed my requests than KeepAlive and multithreading?

Thanks.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without having an idea of what you're trying to do. What information are you trying to extract from these pages?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to extract several stock quotes and financial ratios from the Italian Stock Exchange website. Every page that I load is related to a specific company.

Comment: @user3030211: Are you SURE that requests is what is slow? It's not just the network itself, the server that you are requesting data from, or the software you are using to parse the HTML? Also, does the stock exchange website have an API, which they probably specifically made for these types of things? In any case, there is a good chance that even if there were a tweak for requests that made it 20x faster you would only experience a 0.001x speed increase overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you clarified in a comment:

> Hi, I'm trying to extract several stock quotes and financial ratios from the Italian Stock Exchange website. Every page that I load is related to a specific company.

This means there aren't very many easy optimisations left to make. If the web pages themselves are very large and the data you want is early-on in the page, you might be able to avoid downloading some of the data by [streaming the download](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-requests): that is, setting `stream=True` on the request and then using `Response.iter_content()` to read in chunks at a time.

If you're fortunate, you might be able to take advantage of caching to reduce response times or sizes. Try plugging something like [CacheControl](http://cachecontrol.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) into your `Session` objects to see if this improves anything.

Otherwise, you're already getting almost as big an improvement as you can get in software alone. If the Italian Stock Exchange supports SPDY (they probably don't), using a SPDY library could improve things, but that rules out Requests (and possibly multithreading as well, for reasons that are totally tangential to this answer). Another outside-the-box option is to run on a machine closer to the web server providing the data.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have significantly speed it up with a Range header and now I'm trying to stream the download of the page, to optimize my code further.